# Set work e-mail address to SharePoint Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, groups

Looking at the SharePoint groups in my site, I see there's a column work e-mail. How does this work? Is it possible to set a work e-mail to a SharePoint group? Maybe through Powershell?

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to "move" Distribution Lists in Active Directory to my SharePoint Site, so that these lists are available for selection in a People Picker.

I've read that this can be done by turning the DL into Security Groups, but we would like to avoid this alternative.

I thought maybe this could be done by creating SharePoint groups and adding an email address. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I have seen.

Moving the DLs to SGs is the best option, make them email enabled so they can be managed in Outlook, and you can now use these groups in the email field AND as permissions in your Sharepoint groups.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the quick response! What's the purpose of the work e-mail address then?